# Checking the number of command line arguments in python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I'm new to python.  Still getting my feet wet.  I'm trying to do something like this:

```
import sys

if ((len(sys.argv) < 3 or < len(sys.argv > 3)):
    print """\
This script will compare two files for something
and print out matches

Usage:  theScript firstfile secondfile
"""
    return
```

I want to do this at the beginning of the script to check for the right number of arguments.  The problem is "return" doesn't work here.  I could do some big if then statement I suppose, but was hoping to not have to do that.  Not sure if there is any easier way.  Any ideas?

Comment: I assume you're wrapping in "if \__name__ == '\__main__': ... ", right? Otherwise you're bound to have a bad time. Exit is good. Or only do stuff if good condition is met...

Comment: @UglyCode: I don't think he should return an exit status indicating success.  Apparently his script is being used incorrectly, so it should return a non-zero exit status.

Answer (score 15):

Use `sys.exit()` to exit from a script.

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print """\
This script will compare two files for something
and print out matches

Usage:  theScript firstfile secondfile
"""
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: The program is exiting because there was an error; you should probably use `sys.exit(1)`.

Comment: That's kind of a philosophical point, imho.  Inputting the wrong number of arguments isn't representative of a code failure or system crash.  But if you want to return an error code of `1`, you're welcome to.  :)

Comment: All,  Thank you.  You are all awesome.  Will try "sys.exit(1)".  I'm not sure what "if \_\_name\_\_ == '\_\_main\_\_' ...." means?  Is \_\_name\_\_  the name of the script?  Thanks.

Comment: @mdmenard: `__name__` is `'__main__'` when the file is executed as a program, but is the name of the file if it is imported.  If you put all of your main execution code in an `if` block, then another file can import your file without running the whole code.

Comment: Nitpick: the if clause is wrong (the second parenthesis of the second part of the error. Fixed:
`if len(sys.argv) < 3 or  len(sys.argv) > 3:`

Answer (score 4):

`sys` has a function called `exit`:

```
sys.exit(1)
```

is probably what you want.  Using `1` tells the program calling your program that there was an error.  You should probably consider writing to `sys.stderr` the reason for the error.