# Looping for more arguments in sys

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a program that only runs when a number of valid arguments have been typed from command prompt. But the program will keep looping until "" is entered.

For example:

```
C:\User\ABC>python example.py "argv1" "argv2"

-> do something, then ask to keep prompting for more arguments in command prompt

C:\User\ABC>python example.py

-> no argument, the program will ask for arguments. If "" is entered, the program will exit

C:\User\ABC>python example.py "argv1" "argv2" "argv3"

-> too many arguments, error code display
sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking the number of command line arguments in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491845/checking-the-number-of-command-line-arguments-in-python)

Comment: `argparse` will handle examples 2 and 3 easily. It's not entirely clear what you want for the first example.

Comment: on the first example, if I only enter the program name but don't give any arguments, the program will keep looping and ask me for more. If I enter "" then it will exit.

Comment: Huh? You only get one command line -- you have to exit, not loop, to get another. If you want to prompt for input on stdin, that's doable, but a different thing from the command-line argument list.

Comment: Your comment is more clear, but IMHO contradicts the example of the question...

Comment: sorry about that, I'll edit the example

Comment: I wonder if maybe what you want is something like `if len(sys.argv) > 2: arg2 = sys.argv[2] else: arg2 = raw_input("Please enter a value for argument 2")`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Tks, your example works for me. I'll close the thread.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Can you put it into a post I can mark it as an answer to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something closer to your original request might instead be:

```
while True:
  extra_arg = raw_input("Please enter an additional argument, or press enter when done")
  if extra_arg == "":
      break
  sys.argv.append(extra_arg)
```

...after which you do your regular `len(sys.argv)` processing.

---

A simpler approach for the two-argument case might be more like:

```
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    arg1 = sys.argv[1]
else:
    arg1 = raw_input("Please enter a value for argument 1:")

if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    arg2 = sys.argv[2]
else:
    arg2 = raw_input("Please enter a value for argument 2:")

if len(sys.argv) > 3:
    sys.stderr.write("ERROR: Too many arguments\n")
    sys.exit(1)
```

---

That said, it's more conventional to just exit, and expect the user to rerun the command with the missing arguments added from their prompt, when usage is incorrect.